# Swift Cocoa: WKWebView Twilio Error: Client is unable to create apply a local media description. Error Code: 53400

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, twilio

I am developing a `Cocoa` app that using TwilioVideo. Since `TwilioVideo SDK` is only built for iOS and not worked for `macOS` so I wanted to create an approach using `Twilio` with the shared weblink and work it with `WKWebView` in `Cocoa`. I start with

```
let pRoom = URL(string: "https://meetingroomfortwilio.com/room/roomid")!
let request = URLRequest(url: pRoom)
videoWebView.load(request)
```

in `viewDidLoad` method.

It opened the communication web page but with error like below.

[image]

I searched for error and learned that these problems via `Twilio` official API errors page.

> - The Client may not be using a supported WebRTC implementation.
> - The Client may not have the necessary resources to create or apply a new media description.

So, good or bad, I have to implement a video call system in `Cocoa` for the app.

How can I implement supported `WebRTC` implementation for my app in `Cocoa`?
What would you do for a building an app with `WebRTC` (video & voice call)?
Is opened a `Safari browser` from the app good approach for building this and can I track the browser which I opened for the video-voice call, situations like success, error?

I would like to learn how to achieve the problem, maybe in different ways?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever figure out anything with this? I think i have a similar issue with WkWebView but finding little success for solution

Comment: WKWebView does not support webrtc, for macOS, there are another ways to handle webrtc implementation I guess. What’s your solution?

Comment: For iOS..I don't know yet. I am using Twilio and a support ticket with them. I hope they offer some solutions.